# Eclipse Juno and Retina Resolution

Tags: eclipse, retina-display, eclipse-juno

Is it possible to have Eclipse Juno display at retina resolution? I was able to edit info.plist for previous versions of Eclipse, but this does not work with Juno...

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Open the `<Installation Directory>/Eclipse.app/Contents/Info.plist` with a text editor and add the following **before** `</dict>`:

`<key>NSHighResolutionCapable</key>

<true/>`

If you open the `Info.plist` file with Xcode it should look like that:

[image: Info.plist file after enabling high resolution]

Now make a copy of the Eclipse application (`Eclipse.app`). You can copy it to the same directory it already is; this step is required just to make the OS reload the changes in the `Info.plist` file.

Comment: good tutorial - key thing is that you have to make a copy of the app for the changes to take effect

Comment: Great! But, I'm wondering why this trick doesn't work for other apps (I tried the same for TextWrangler and the text is still displayed blurry)

Comment: You won't be able to use this approach with all applications. In fact, most applications that are already retina-compatible won't require you to do anything.

Comment: "touch <Installation Directory>/Eclipse.app" seems also to force reload, no need to copy dir.

Comment: Confirmed. You either need to touch the app (as above) or duplicate the eclipse directory, delete the old one, and rename the new one. Anything to force the refresh of the plist cache.

Comment: Confirmed. You either need to touch the app (as above) or duplicate the eclipse directory, delete the old one, and rename the new one. Anything to force the refresh of the plist cache.

Comment: Just a note textwrangler finally came out with retina resolution! (yeah it was a few months ago but just found out myself)

Comment: Use *lsregister*.   See the "Thelle" post.  This is guarantee to work.

Answer (score 5):

Force update the `Info.plist` in the Terminal by using the lsregister command:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Support/lsregister -v -f /Applications/eclipse/Eclipse.app
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an app called Retinizer which will convert Apps to Retina mode. Easier. Only really works for fonts though.

http://retinizer.mikelpr.com

Comment: does this alter other features of the app?

Comment: Only the text. Images scale but won't look great as they aren't designed for the resolution. But at least makes the apps usable.

Answer (score -2):

After updating High Resolution Capable to Yes in plist, make a copy of the app.

Comment: For clarification: at the time, this was the answer. You could get retina resolution to show after copying the app after updating plist. Please don't downvote for the wrong reason.